# Sum of autocovariance function for AR(2) process

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Consider a stationary AR(2) model:

$y_t=\alpha_1y_{t-1}+\alpha_2y_{t-2}+\varepsilon_t$, where
$\varepsilon_t$ is $WN(0, \sigma^2)$.

I understand that the long-run variance of AR(2) should be $\Omega=\gamma(0)+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\gamma(k)$.

However, **I have trouble finding the value of** $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\gamma(k)$.

I also know that for $k>1$, an AR(2)'s ACF has the property of $\rho(k)=\alpha_1\rho_{k-1}+\alpha_2\rho_{k-2}$. Feels like I should use this, my approach is to divide $\Omega$ by $\gamma_0$, and the long run variance is then $\Omega/\gamma_0=1+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\rho(k)$.

But I also have trouble finding the sum of all $\rho(k)$.

Can you help me?